# Soft delete in laravel is not hiding record in view

Tags: laravel

I am using Eloquent soft delete to delete a row in the database. I use function destroy, in database column `deleted_at` have a date, but this is not hiding deleted records in view.
My code in controller.

```
$query = Role::join('users', 'roles.id', '=','users.role_id');
$user = User::all();
$users = $query->select('users.*','roles.name as role_name')->paginate(10);
```

My code in User Model

```
use SoftDeletes;
use HasFactory;

protected $table = 'users';
protected $guarded = [];
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token', 'deleted_at'
];

public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

My code in Models Role

```
use HasFactory;

protected $table = 'roles';
protected $guarded = [];

public function users() {
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

Comment: You can use the `$hidden` property `protected $hidden = ['deleted_at'];`

Comment: not working bro :(

Comment: add some code to your question. what have you tried and why's not that working. it's tough to guess and find a solution.

Comment: updated code in models Role. Someone help me fix this bug.

Comment: added an answer for you. check that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems, the problem here is the join. Soft delete is an Eloquent feature which works on the model itself but not on the joined table. In case you have to join two tables, you have to query yourself to drop out the deleted column. In your case you can do it like

```
$query = Role::join('users', 'roles.id', '=', 'users.role_id');
$user = User::all();
$users = $query->select('users.*', 'roles.name as role_name')->where('users.deleted_at', null)->paginate(10);
```

so this will drop out the deleted column. but as you are using relationship, why you have to join yourself?? the relationship will handle that for you. you can simply call like

```
$roles = Role::with('users')->get();
```

and you can get every users of a role like

```
foreach ($roles as $role) {
    foreach ($role->users as $user) {
        echo $user->attribute;
    }
}
```

and a note for you. you need to pass the foreign key name as the second parameter of the relationship definition as it's not matching the laravel's naming convention.

```
public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id');
}
```

and

```
public function users() {
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'role_id');
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I can fix it with your solution. thank you so much. love you 3000 <3

Comment: glad that helped. check this as the accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you used eloquent relationship it would worked but now you are using join. the login of eloquent orm is this, you can write your SQL and query it but you have to manually select which do you want or not want(in this case you dont want the records that `deleted_at` column is filled. but if you use relationships you can have the benefits of soft delete and many other features.

Comment: thank you for reply. but why project other can do, but this project not working?
how to fix?

Comment: well the other project maybe use different than this example. maybe u used user instead of Role model. and if u try join user to roles model maybe fixed but only deleted users detected not roles. i would say use relationships instead of joins because of two reasons 1- its easier :) 2- have more benefits. yes joins have more performance but in most apps you dont feel that.